Как лучше реализовать очередь через микросервисы?
Хочу распилить монолит (back - flask) и сделать отдельный сервис (№1) со своей API по которой он будет принимать данные и записывать в БД.
Другой сервис(№2) (на Airflow) будет стучатьсся на №1 по API, и запускать выполнение задач, записанных в БД в сервисе №1
Т.е. получается следующая схема: Монолит отдает на запись часть задач в сервис №1 -> Сервис №2 по API дергает сервис №1, который смотрит есть ли у него задачи и выполняет их. После выполнения стирает из БД выполненные задачи.
Собственно сам вопрос нормальное ли решение или мне посмотреть что-нибудь, что уже решает текущий пул?
